# Conditionally Delete html Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If div `.element` has specific class `.block` / `<div class="element block">` then delete html node `.element img`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="element">
<img src="images/picture.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/picture.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Want to delete `img`, how to do this by Jquery?

Comment: `$('.element.block img').remove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something simple like that?

```
$('.element.block').find('img').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.element.block img').remove ()
```

This removes only images which are in blocks with the both classes